# Unit and step of coordinates of spatial frequency Discret Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, image-processing

I'm trying to understand spacial frequency Fourier Transform.

If I perform the 2D Fourier Transform of an image of $n_x*n_y$ pixels and I know that the measurement step is $\Delta L$ (in $\mu m$) in both directions.

If I want to plot the result with $\mu m^{-1}$ unit in both direction, what is the step value of the coordinates in the spacial frequency Fourier domain ?

Is it $\Delta f_x = \Delta f_y = \frac{1}{\Delta L}$ ? With $\Delta f_x$ and $\Delta f_y$ the steps in spacial frequency.